# In @ManyToMany hibernate mapping, mappedby side will not trigger relationship persistence?

Tags: hibernate, mapping, persistence, relationship

is it true that in a @ManyToMany relationship, the side annotated with "mappedby" will not trigger relationship persistence? For example,

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="joinedTopicGroups")
public List<User> getContainedUsers() {
  return containedUsers;
}

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "UserInTopicGroup", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "groupID"))
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
public List<TopicGroup> getJoinedTopicGroups() {
    return joinedTopicGroups;
}
```

If I add a user into the 'containedUsers', will the relationship be persisted into table UserInTopicGroup?

Comment: And the answer is no. However if you declare `CASCADE`, not persisted `User` object can by persisted by adding to `containedUsers` and updating entity holding it. Ofc only user table will be updated (along with its children if cascading deeper into hierarhy or children are already persisted)

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a working bidirectional relation, you will need to add the references to both sides of the relation:

```
myGroup.getContainedUsers().add(newUser);
newUser.getJoinedTopicGroups(myGroup);
```

JPA will do nothing to enforce correct relationship mapping on the object side.